# SQL Server doesn´t recognize polygon

Tags: geospatial, sql-server-2016, polygons, geography

I extracted the polygon coordinates from a bunch of districts from openstreetmap. To my surprise when I run it, it doesn´t recognize it as a polygon while when I draw it by linestring it draws it correctly. Can anyone tell me why and how to fix it?

I am using SQL server 2016

```
declare @poly geography
declare @linestring geography
set @poly=geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-3.7251721 40.3346954,-3.7211547 40.3654057,-3.7190862 40.3649337,-3.7160496 40.3645544,-3.711698 40.3641097,-3.7059412 40.3638936,-3.7022824 40.3635865,-3.6997332 40.3640443,-3.6977591 40.3643909,-3.6961026 40.3645347,-3.6927981 40.3645086,-3.6915554 40.364468,-3.6903977 40.3642285,-3.6886353 40.3637042,-3.6830306 40.3617095,-3.6819717 40.3614412,-3.6814057 40.3600219,-3.6806572 40.3595494,-3.6792339 40.3581255,-3.6785129 40.3577919,-3.6778348 40.3575499,-3.6773971 40.357151,-3.6771124 40.3566378,-3.6768833 40.3557292,-3.6766677 40.3550021,-3.676415 40.3542448,-3.6758092 40.3537694,-3.6747621 40.3535601,-3.674187 40.3533181,-3.6738523 40.3530892,-3.6736806 40.3528145,-3.6736034 40.3521342,-3.6734648 40.3514367,-3.6732923 40.3509194,-3.6729425 40.3504859,-3.6725305 40.3502111,-3.6719211 40.3499822,-3.670256 40.3495178,-3.6697974 40.3492625,-3.6694766 40.3489478,-3.668994 40.3474553,-3.6690075 40.3468868,-3.6690911 40.3463332,-3.6692012 40.3459511,-3.6693869 40.3456349,-3.6694909 40.3454513,-3.6693897 40.3452304,-3.6689857 40.3449649,-3.6684603 40.3447916,-3.6680641 40.344684,-3.6666032 40.3443162,-3.6651576 40.3440622,-3.6646598 40.3438528,-3.6642958 40.3434826,-3.6640332 40.3427015,-3.6636899 40.3422435,-3.6631578 40.3412164,-3.6628402 40.3391622,-3.66272 40.3388874,-3.6622308 40.3385734,-3.6617983 40.3382015,-3.6615613 40.3379977,-3.661424 40.3375986,-3.6613982 40.3370556,-3.6612094 40.3363882,-3.6605485 40.3354265,-3.6596387 40.3346545,-3.6587804 40.3337254,-3.6585229 40.3332674,-3.6584628 40.3324953,-3.6582568 40.3316317,-3.657816 40.3307174,-3.6576732 40.3304212,-3.657359 40.3290369,-3.6592657 40.3282873,-3.660041 40.3281207,-3.6606531 40.3281172,-3.6612437 40.328321,-3.662074 40.328965,-3.6628079 40.3293842,-3.663539 40.3295061,-3.6662634 40.3276346,-3.6669148 40.3268381,-3.6676037 40.3262755,-3.6686923 40.3256476,-3.6693252 40.3253737,-3.6704523 40.3250789,-3.67128 40.3254525,-3.674173 40.3263726,-3.6755624 40.3264096,-3.6776978 40.3268926,-3.6786043 40.3269053,-3.6794497 40.3266931,-3.6799414 40.32642,-3.6804064 40.3258407,-3.6808917 40.3249369,-3.681206 40.3245837,-3.6830826 40.323915,-3.6834104 40.3237328,-3.6848 40.3226345,-3.6859754 40.3224744,-3.6876934 40.3224282,-3.6889852 40.3221322,-3.693432 40.3207453,-3.6964539 40.3227452,-3.7014914 40.3227148,-3.7037032 40.3226113,-3.7044926 40.3226876,-3.7099055 40.3236726,-3.712603 40.3238632,-3.7130333 40.3256084,-3.7135981 40.326704,-3.7148182 40.3285524,-3.7161782 40.3291476,-3.7201193 40.3311322,-3.7228013 40.3328939,-3.723 40.3330242,-3.7235589 40.3335523,-3.7251721 40.3346954))',4326)
set @linestring=geography::STLineFromText('LINESTRING(-3.7251721 40.3346954,-3.7211547 40.3654057,-3.7190862 40.3649337,-3.7160496 40.3645544,-3.711698 40.3641097,-3.7059412 40.3638936,-3.7022824 40.3635865,-3.6997332 40.3640443,-3.6977591 40.3643909,-3.6961026 40.3645347,-3.6927981 40.3645086,-3.6915554 40.364468,-3.6903977 40.3642285,-3.6886353 40.3637042,-3.6830306 40.3617095,-3.6819717 40.3614412,-3.6814057 40.3600219,-3.6806572 40.3595494,-3.6792339 40.3581255,-3.6785129 40.3577919,-3.6778348 40.3575499,-3.6773971 40.357151,-3.6771124 40.3566378,-3.6768833 40.3557292,-3.6766677 40.3550021,-3.676415 40.3542448,-3.6758092 40.3537694,-3.6747621 40.3535601,-3.674187 40.3533181,-3.6738523 40.3530892,-3.6736806 40.3528145,-3.6736034 40.3521342,-3.6734648 40.3514367,-3.6732923 40.3509194,-3.6729425 40.3504859,-3.6725305 40.3502111,-3.6719211 40.3499822,-3.670256 40.3495178,-3.6697974 40.3492625,-3.6694766 40.3489478,-3.668994 40.3474553,-3.6690075 40.3468868,-3.6690911 40.3463332,-3.6692012 40.3459511,-3.6693869 40.3456349,-3.6694909 40.3454513,-3.6693897 40.3452304,-3.6689857 40.3449649,-3.6684603 40.3447916,-3.6680641 40.344684,-3.6666032 40.3443162,-3.6651576 40.3440622,-3.6646598 40.3438528,-3.6642958 40.3434826,-3.6640332 40.3427015,-3.6636899 40.3422435,-3.6631578 40.3412164,-3.6628402 40.3391622,-3.66272 40.3388874,-3.6622308 40.3385734,-3.6617983 40.3382015,-3.6615613 40.3379977,-3.661424 40.3375986,-3.6613982 40.3370556,-3.6612094 40.3363882,-3.6605485 40.3354265,-3.6596387 40.3346545,-3.6587804 40.3337254,-3.6585229 40.3332674,-3.6584628 40.3324953,-3.6582568 40.3316317,-3.657816 40.3307174,-3.6576732 40.3304212,-3.657359 40.3290369,-3.6592657 40.3282873,-3.660041 40.3281207,-3.6606531 40.3281172,-3.6612437 40.328321,-3.662074 40.328965,-3.6628079 40.3293842,-3.663539 40.3295061,-3.6662634 40.3276346,-3.6669148 40.3268381,-3.6676037 40.3262755,-3.6686923 40.3256476,-3.6693252 40.3253737,-3.6704523 40.3250789,-3.67128 40.3254525,-3.674173 40.3263726,-3.6755624 40.3264096,-3.6776978 40.3268926,-3.6786043 40.3269053,-3.6794497 40.3266931,-3.6799414 40.32642,-3.6804064 40.3258407,-3.6808917 40.3249369,-3.681206 40.3245837,-3.6830826 40.323915,-3.6834104 40.3237328,-3.6848 40.3226345,-3.6859754 40.3224744,-3.6876934 40.3224282,-3.6889852 40.3221322,-3.693432 40.3207453,-3.6964539 40.3227452,-3.7014914 40.3227148,-3.7037032 40.3226113,-3.7044926 40.3226876,-3.7099055 40.3236726,-3.712603 40.3238632,-3.7130333 40.3256084,-3.7135981 40.326704,-3.7148182 40.3285524,-3.7161782 40.3291476,-3.7201193 40.3311322,-3.7228013 40.3328939,-3.723 40.3330242,-3.7235589 40.3335523,-3.7251721 40.3346954)',4326)

select @poly as polygon, @linestring as linestring
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: There isn´t any error message. If you run the statement in SSMS in spatial results you will see that if you choose to see the linestring it draws it correctly, while if you choose the polygon it doesn´t draw anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change
`declare @poly geography` and `set @poly=geography::STPolyFromText...`
to
`declare @poly geometry` and `set @poly=geometry ::STPolyFromText...`

you will see polygon drawn in the spatial results tab.

Comment: Thanks Mountaineer. I am still wondering why it doesn´t work with geography, but with geometry it does what I want.